# How to control joints with Foxy and Edifice?

Tags: ros, ros-foxy, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am assuming there is something similar to the [gazebo_ros_control](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros_control) plugin.

Is such a plugin already available? Are there examples?

If not, will a similar paradigm be used in Edifice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26789/how-to-control-joints-with-foxy-and-edifice?/) by [andy.mcevoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37/andy.mcevoy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The closest thing to `gazebo_ros_control` for Ignition/ROS 2 is [`ign_ros2_control`](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign_ros2_control), with its recently opened [PR](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign_ros2_control/pull/1). You can hear more information about it in  [Edifice Demos! Ignition Community Meeting (March 2021)](https://youtu.be/aKpUSXgZXYM?t=2079).

If you need something more simple/custom, you can also use [`JointController`](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/blob/26832764749291b6ea22b525262136ecbb63fbb9/examples/worlds/joint_controller.sdf), [`JointPositionController`](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/blob/26832764749291b6ea22b525262136ecbb63fbb9/examples/worlds/joint_position_controller.sdf) or [`JointTrajectoryController` (for multiple joints)](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/blob/26832764749291b6ea22b525262136ecbb63fbb9/examples/worlds/joint_trajectory_controller.sdf) in combination with [`ros_ign_bridge` (`ros2` branch)](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/ros2/ros_ign_bridge), i.e. publish commands in ROS 2 and subscribe to them in the individual Ignition `Joint*Controller` plugin(s).

---

Originally posted by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) with karma: 101 on 2021-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0